# Hotmail/Outlook don't show body of Python SMTPLib Email

Tags: email, outlook, smtp, html-email

I'm trying to send an email with Python's `smtplib` but it simply shows up blank in Hotmail/Outlook. Everything is fine in other providers, with the email raw content showing the html body in base64. But not in Hotmail/Outlook!! It doesn't even show the content section of my message.

I'm on this for several hours now, I have no idea how to solve it. Anyone been through this before? Here is my code:

```
text = f"Este és su código. Este cógido caduca en 1 hora."
html = (
    f'''
        <html>
            <body>
                <p>Este és su código.</p>
                <p style=\"color:tomato; font-size:25px;letter-spacing:2px;\"><b>1234</b></p><p>Este código <b>caduca en 1 hora</b>.</p>
            </body>
        </html>
    '''
)

port = 465
smtp_server = "smtpout.secureserver.net"
email_domain = "mydomain.com"

content = MIMEMultipart("mixed")
content["Subject"] = subject
content["From"] = f"My User<{EMAIL_ADDRESS}>"
content["To"] = company.email
content['Date'] = email.utils.formatdate()
content['Message-ID'] = email.utils.make_msgid(domain=email_domain)

body = MIMEMultipart("alternative")

part1 = MIMEText(text, "plain", 'UTF-8')
part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")

body.attach(part1)
body.attach(part2)

content.attach(body)

context = ssl.create_default_context()

try:
    # Python 3 libraries expect bytes.
    msg_data = content.as_bytes()
except:
    # Python 2 libraries expect strings.
    msg_data = content.as_string()


with SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
    server.sendmail(EMAIL_ADDRESS, company.email, msg_data)
```

Tried adding leading blank lines in the HTML, no success. I expect the email body to be shown in Hotmail/Outlook.

This is my `msg_data` variable:

```
b'Content-Type: multipart/alternative;\n boundary="===============6009941277021292094=="\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nSubject: =?utf-8?q?Restablezca_su_contrase=C3=B1a_de_Pix_Global?=\nFrom: Pix Global <hola@globalpix.shop>\nTo: matheusmansourteste@hotmail.com\nDate: Sun, 24 Sep 2023 14:20:26 -0000\nMessage-ID: <169556522613.8.11777963384777140395@globalpix.shop>\nDKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=globalpix.shop;\n i=@globalpix.shop; q=dns/txt; s=20230818; t=1695565226; h=to : from :\n subject; bh=H5ViRl7MX8W8vE0Xl9ATs0qJDS5xj24KAAdRTa8kNJ0=;\n b=XVWSKZshE+RNUa//VNsMSj7fOty5UMlnCq2n01N34KLrJW02QSeu9MZywUahjxdiiLZav\n cT5ZeikXEyBSfZux6pvn0Ze4AqxbVz6H89XvLCMHIMgeIONr/LAm3q/7LmZKS42vTsGb+iL\n lij5O31TU5a8vTMpke5ukBom/sUFQqA=\n\n--===============6009941277021292094==\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\nRnJvbTogaG9sYUBnbG9iYWxwaXguc2hvcA0KVG86IG1hdGhldXNtYW5zb3VydGVzdGVAaG90bWFp\nbC5jb20NCg0Kw4lzdGUgZXMgc3UgUElOIGRlIFBpeCBHbG9iYWwgcGFyYSByZXN0YWJsZWNlciBz\ndSBjb250cmFzZcOxYS4uIEVzdGUgY8OzZ2lkbyBjYWR1Y2EgZW4gMSBob3JhLg==\n\n--===============6009941277021292094==\nContent-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\nRnJvbTogaG9sYUBnbG9iYWxwaXguc2hvcA0KVG86IG1hdGhldXNtYW5zb3VydGVzdGVAaG90bWFp\nbC5jb20NCg0KPGh0bWw+PGJvZHk+PHA+w4lzdGUgZXMgc3UgUElOIGRlIFBpeCBHbG9iYWwgcGFy\nYSByZXN0YWJsZWNlciBzdSBjb250cmFzZcOxYS48L3A+PHAgc3R5bGU9ImNvbG9yOnRvbWF0bzsK\nZm9udC1zaXplOjI1cHg7bGV0dGVyLXNwYWNpbmc6MnB4OyI+PGI+OTg3MjwvYj48L3A+CjxwPkVz\ndGUgY8OzZGlnbyA8Yj5jYWR1Y2EgZW4gMSBob3JhPC9iPi48L3A+PC9ib2R5PjwvaHRtbD4=\n\n--===============6009941277021292094==--\n'
```

Outlook Message Source:

```
Received: from SJ0PR03MB7080.namprd03.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:a03:4e9::11)
 by CY4PR03MB3399.namprd03.prod.outlook.com with HTTPS; Wed, 27 Sep 2023
 03:26:58 +0000
Received: from MW4PR03CA0006.namprd03.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:303:8f::11)
 by SJ0PR03MB7080.namprd03.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:a03:4e9::11) with
 Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.6813.21; Wed, 27 Sep
 2023 03:26:58 +0000
Received: from CO1NAM11FT064.eop-nam11.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (2603:10b6:303:8f:cafe::ed) by MW4PR03CA0006.outlook.office365.com
 (2603:10b6:303:8f::11) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.6792.35 via Frontend
 Transport; Wed, 27 Sep 2023 03:26:57 +0000
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 97.74.135.230)
 smtp.mailfrom=globalpix.shop; dkim=none (message not signed)
 header.d=none;dmarc=pass action=none header.from=globalpix.shop;compauth=pass
 reason=100
Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of globalpix.shop
 designates 97.74.135.230 as permitted sender)
 receiver=protection.outlook.com; client-ip=97.74.135.230;
 helo=p3plsmtpa14-10.prod.phx3.secureserver.net; pr=C
Received: from p3plsmtpa14-10.prod.phx3.secureserver.net (97.74.135.230) by
 CO1NAM11FT064.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.13.175.77) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id
 15.20.6838.21 via Frontend Transport; Wed, 27 Sep 2023 03:26:57 +0000
X-IncomingTopHeaderMarker:
 OriginalChecksum:010B9E785D7A8D5F802268200768DD3279404A2F7EC607EAC9DB5F0D75EA68EF;UpperCasedChecksum:50EF3B1D2877EE5C1BCA5DC065E0FC5C1AAD2A0E3A3FBF36F0C7B5861C041DC1;SizeAsReceived:2000;Count:11
Received: from [172.18.0.2] ([191.17.88.132])
    by :SMTPAUTH: with ESMTPSA
    id lLCRqVyd1gLd2lLCSqc8gQ; Tue, 26 Sep 2023 20:26:57 -0700
X-CMAE-Analysis: v=2.4 cv=b9d0oPKx c=1 sm=1 tr=0 ts=6513a101
 a=GTfYd3sRU+i6G4xf9tOLfQ==:117 a=GTfYd3sRU+i6G4xf9tOLfQ==:17
 a=MKtGQD3n3ToA:10 a=1oJP67jkp3AA:10 a=dCs_blNjXhEA:10 a=5KLPUuaC_9wA:10
 a=CYqRCMiiIZHEVys7HUIA:9 a=QEXdDO2ut3YA:10 a=58YBMok73DsF6R3qTEYA:9
 a=_W_S_7VecoQA:10
X-SECURESERVER-ACCT: hola@globalpix.shop
Content-Type: text/plain
Subject: =?utf-8?q?Restablezca_su_contrase=C3=B1a_de_Pix_Global=3A_1653?=
From: Pix Global <hola@globalpix.shop>
To: matheusmansourteste@hotmail.com
Date: Sun, 24 Sep 2023 16:53:53 -0000
Message-ID: <169557443331.35.14257289435189887927@globalpix.shop>
X-CMAE-Envelope: MS4xfCviOwvmudnYh3rvEvF/2Q8q0I68VChNvfuBcwwl8mQL/k1BY3fEUNshWhHB3DqeXNm3poFIoQMAVeAsfLRo7noEkYrptmqV+sdJ/WSm0GhO80gBB9MJ
 4Kqlg1wCFqyUOF+zdZmBKCqYmUhKC6yuRhFtift8uJFj4xmqvRRYfYLSrJCrtEsswwm0zlawTKVwQfLU+9TkS8dR5fcFf3K7prE=
X-IncomingHeaderCount: 11
Return-Path: hola@globalpix.shop
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTime: 27 Sep 2023 03:26:57.9283
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTimeReason: OriginalSubmit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationInterval: 1:00:00:00.0000000
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationIntervalReason: OriginalSubmit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id:
 d76bd302-9b3c-431b-3e22-08dbbf099b02
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa:0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic:
 CO1NAM11FT064:EE_|SJ0PR03MB7080:EE_|CY4PR03MB3399:EE_
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource:
 CO1NAM11FT064.eop-nam11.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-UserLastLogonTime: 9/27/2023 3:11:11 AM
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: d76bd302-9b3c-431b-3e22-08dbbf099b02
X-MS-Exchange-EOPDirect: true
X-Sender-IP: 97.74.135.230
X-SID-PRA: HOLA@GLOBALPIX.SHOP
X-SID-Result: PASS
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PCL: 2
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 1
X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 27 Sep 2023 03:26:57.7721
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: d76bd302-9b3c-431b-3e22-08dbbf099b02
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthSource:
 CO1NAM11FT064.eop-nam11.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-RMS-PersistedConsumerOrg:
 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: SJ0PR03MB7080
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:01.2273647
X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering: 15.20.6813.027
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    wl:1;pcwl:1;ucf:0;jmr:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:I;OFR:TrustedSenderList;ENG:(5062000305)(920221119095)(90000117)(920221120095)(91040095)(9050020)(9060121)(9100341)(944500132)(2008001134)(4810010)(4910033)(9930004)(9545005)(10172021)(9439006)(9310011)(9220031)(120001);
X-Message-Info:
    qZelhIiYnPlDALU4MEr+nZRXojxj8gEC6CFLScfQxVf6dHI0/ZZuX393R27b5Tlw1d+U36zzw7WMxDWPLADTJMgniNHoqap1CaLhi2snzZcu/i0d2eM9tr+Tz0sPOR20nABo1trfoBPIyRUOfNdDnS/X8D9xQxbCRsaEtx64Lp5RrlJG0cfXKWy6w+Svie9p+RG9Ii1bseIS6kZn7rO7Yg==
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MTtHRD0yO1NDTD0tMQ==
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:
    =?iso-8859-1?Q?zzf2sspx8xNxHZnSiMC2dvppZRK9+0cve53FR1a/aZoGM7HiWeL8pGCWWK?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?j4yJUiql21jtKlgXdMqf3EbduSdshr1Z6tsKkCVq7io2WqUbEexf3RyeDo?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?kKZpLFDKih7ZnYxaoMkycBq7PECCZ+ZaJwu9SN83oEV3X0qftLaqZLGvpz?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?iAMUhL+nXm3zvpWYuMZSycEeQSFyKcs78YyuzuhaL/SKNwAJs/nC/BJFMB?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?wZpg/3Be7J1tz9bSw5N+BXWcCatPefB6X+gyK7JraBvFcf4ertKtPtZ8oY?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?i8/y48zZJi2xGD4qzYIVUoDDOOLfEIUALcyQ1h5DNTmOYjUSUK1QTbxLaX?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?Qj38DGxPan8tx43qw4sU1TvsPrupmdFiAeRegFZ3ePUTtze0sicDltkOEB?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?6lUv+3g52y+8gBvhTrxGmFcQkt3P4F+/nk4zStvZyiYXLfA365p16mi1+c?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?4O34Qoi6KVW68vHkYaKhWWRpGEvEWRci96kKllvJNrAg9oSIiya3YBWODE?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?VRNHbzb9WUu7jCjeV197zLXx2azpZCyZBmvHawyytZoH8JD+fk4n+5cePM?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?y5s1qWDbPRvoXtGqvLfOLtfaVcoLRljU3ngau1W6QDAqT0gxUXKkN5kY71?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?m5JDGLz7j24S1cOKDj5oLQNYFCVLVB7nFGVAoBZRHx6QPncGbbNWqX0mJC?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?j7fyYmu8NBewgoafH1z5fM+SJ2vcbG+MoKo6LWb/x6N+Hh3ah3QLYBx4mN?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?2dc6C4HukJcAjDjyxDZLBZa34DE/vSdIDCIrMxQpqaEE6ieO7Hm2rnFzS9?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?NzJZvOOVhJ+TsublVQt/K/WunBONx2WrEK/eO5mIB6gVNaU/ERJuV/coeP?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?x10Uwcuotl7/774fDCNXuyYYETUhJJFR3/4gSjena2W0etVi5JUxSnUv8T?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?IcLn7AxBZSVLQYvDLAB1XwUoWQn2bijB00fYQp7koQzFqcHrN0ihYr8GSq?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?MpF3mBy/j+aiBiZcW1pMbZ0SvSVkWT9jb9qTXLWtxvOpGtLEVe/9SjZk1l?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?ZQAa/eMiJHxaNK9bM8JQAvDiYWGWx6zr95OZN7eT1BaSAvwEn2s8190/bX?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?s/zQg8B0TrSYt030/yGhLtX3UzLABN0RanwC/wtj9InsZ03eqwhy4CncVy?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?1TTNLCJJykOVmtR0wMrSAfWMb9NFZt48jxXhbst3ybFxQbBRb50UUT8iaH?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?ChSHllvW83Fl2M/ZThMtCuD/0kYT6x6qgZVnpoUU5mc8fulNXoB/cPmN0v?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?5QEKKZLJyDrxwW4awZeWzillFFQI8RQCUQx8n7388GjV7TKal1uA/2DWn5?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?0t2R2Y4e+GqanAXwIY8+aYq2SMDL/h5l4+XNOShR/9osRmKIUgbZCIUOeM?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?b7/o82G/zP/uqFSei3UXQxzKYjD6aLYNG27hIXYDmdgtpko+IQHq7VgJ2F?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?aktnwwg4EN1nawA3j3fbC5WV6sGF8JQON9E+JW/MgE/3iJqpMmhhCFfuXS?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?k85l+A+juN78Tn/ZBZcAXNhSt+cPOQ2YPnZacO+Wd2wVmg3iGiitXLAC8D?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?3ZPuC6XKzHI8UENmZTLvQozEvsQ1TomfkP51Qxl2JdKiJl7dNcCytXBgdY?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?avILLi8yTWFkcPfLHLBtQFvHPNkrWbC90fryniPCIobid1aliu3dH25h5y?=
 =?iso-8859-1?Q?hmoRTkj1WTCQb8vTaF/xMnvsI=3D?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Comment: Please show the complete MIME source of the message you are sending.

Comment: Hi @DmitryStreblechenko, thank you for your answer. I've added the msg_data variable.

Comment: Looks perfectly fine to me if I save it to an eml file and open it with Outlook. If you send it to a Gmail mailbox and then look at the message source, is that what you see?

Comment: Yes, if I send it to Gmail, Yahoo, Yandex,... it shows up perfectly as it should in the msg_data variable. However, when that variable is sent to Hotmail/Outlook by the smtp server in question, the raw message is completely different. It shows no body content whatsoever, as updated at the end of the question.

Do you think it might have to do with the smtp server type? I'm pretty new to all this.

Comment: You are only showing the headers, not the actual MIME structure. I believe Outlook will hide things if it thinks the message is all attachments, or something like that. We'd need to see the individual MIME parts with their respective headers, too. (Unfortunately, Outlook makes this inordinately hard. Try sending a new message from Outlook to yourself at some non-Microsoft service, and drag the interesting sample message over into the new message so it appears as an attachment. Then on whatever other service you are using, you should be able to properly view the source of the message.)

Comment: One thing I noticed, is that you are only using \n for line breaks, while the Windows standard is \r\n. Does that make a difference?

Comment: As an aside, your code seems to be written for Python 3.5 or earlier. The email library was overhauled in 3.6 and is now quite a bit more versatile and logical. Probably throw away what you have and start over with the [examples from the `email` documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko No, it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you very much @tripleee and @DmitryStreblechenko! The new email lib version seems to be functioning properly with HTML on Outlook/Hotmail. I think that is sufficient to know for this problem, what do you think?

Comment: If it solved your problem, probably yes.